# How can I delete content (CheckBox) in a ListView and on a serverside database with long press for android application?

Tags: java, android, database

I have searched multiple sites/threads pertaining to this problem and cannot seem to figure out how to go about doing this.  As of now I am trying to use the long press Context Menu method to try and delete the long pressed list view item in my app.  My main question would be how to retrieve the information within the List View, like the check box text so I can send it as a key to delete it in the database. Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean getting the position of item being long pressed? If yes,

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int position = info.position;

    // Here you will do things like Object selectedObject = myList.get(position);
    // And your server stuffs.
}
```